# how to print the content of a tablelayoutpanel in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, label, tablelayout

i have a winform with a tablelayoutpanel that holds several labels that i change according to input from a calling function (list of strings)

i use labels as it's more easy to change fonts ect... and see it on screen

but when i want to print it i get blank pages,
used

```
private void CaptureScreen()
{
    Graphics myGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
    Size s = this.Size;
    memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics);
    Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
    memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, 0, 0, s);
}
```

[How to: Print a Windows Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6he9hz8c(v=vs.110).aspx)
[image: form]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DrawToBitmap()` like this:

```
    private void CaptureScreen()
    {
        memoryImage = new Bitmap(this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height);
        this.DrawToBitmap(memoryImage, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), this.Size));
    }
```